# Adding/set variable to Array from another method

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Ok, so I'm more of a dunce than a beginner so bear with me.
What I'm trying to accomplished is to try to set/add variable within an array.
The question I am doing is to create a package and call another method called addAccommodation(); and use that method to add the required info and adding it to TravelPackage travelpackage.

I'm posting section of the issue here. The arraylist is called travelPackages and the one I want to add variables into is TravelPackage travelpackage.
(addAccommodation(); is the method soppose to lead another section, and travelpackage.setAccID is the issue I'm trying to solve)

```
public void addPackages() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input Customer ID: ");
    int customerID = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Input Duration in Days: ");
    int duration = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    
    System.out.print("Date in format yyyy-mm-dd? ");
    String date = input.nextLine();
      LocalDate startDate = null;
      try{
       startDate = LocalDate.parse(date);
     }
      catch(Exception e){}
    
    TravelPackage travelpackage = new TravelPackage(customerID, duration, startDate);
    travelPackages.add(travelpackage);
    addAccommodation(); 

}

public void addAccommodation(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     boolean match = false;
      while(true) {
        System.out.print("Input Accommodation Type(Hotel, Lodge, Ski Club, Apartment, Village): ");
        String type = input.nextLine();
         for (Accommodation a: accommodations) {
          if (a.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(type) && a.getAvailability()) {
            // Update accommodation status  in ArrayList
            a.setAvailability(false);
            travelpackage.setAccID(a.getAccID());
            // Set match flag to break loop
             match = true;
            // Stop searching for matching bike
             break;
           }
         }
         if(match){
          System.out.println("Did not find a match.");
          break;
         }
      }    
}
```

It keep saying cannot find symbol. Is there something I'm missing here? (Sorry if I can't provide proper info, I am quite dumb)

Comment: You declare the variable `travelpackage` inside `addPackages` and try to use it inside `addAccommodation` where it's not in scope. Is this variable require definition as a private member? static? Before you continue, I recommend reading some material about java access modifiers and about class and method scope to better understand what's going on!

Comment: I do not know sorry. I just want to know if it's possible to add/set AccID onto the travelpackage that was done from the previous within addPackage.

Comment: I see the problem is you are declaring the instance travelpackage and adding it to an arraylist travelPackages in your addPackages method. And now you want to use the same travelpackage object and set the accID in your addAccommodation method. When you want to use the object in another method, you need to pass this object reference to this new method.  So, your call to addAccommodation() should be addAccommodation(travelPackages).